# Is Java.awt.geom suitable for discrete calculations?

Tags: java, geometry, awt, floating-accuracy

The package [java.awt.geom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/package-summary.html) allows testing if a point lies within a rectangle and similar questions. In particular I need to know if a rectangle is intersected by a line. All involved values are integers.

However, it appears we cannot have those calculations use integers instead of floating point. As I need a completely consistent and reproducible result (its factual accuracy is not as important, actually), I am worried this might be a bad approach. The program will be deployed on Windows, Linux and Android platform, and I do not have full control over the machines.

I have implemented the required algorithm myself (using pure integer arithmetic), and it suffices all my needs. Yet, if possible, I would like to use the preprovided package. Is there some sort of guarantee on its consistency?

Comment: @AndrewThompson That is a good point, I will check.

Comment: @AndrewThompson As far as I can tell you're right. Apparently, while J2SE bytecode can be converted (easily), native libs like awt have and will not be ported to Android. Could you add that as an answer so I can accept it? (Even though it does not exactly answer my initial question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yet, if possible, I would like to use the preprovided package.

It is unlikely the J2SE classes will be available in Android, so stick with your own custom rolled solution.